# Fluentd and S3 - is there a way to do submatching or must I provide separate match statements for each tag path?

Tags: fluentd

Ok so I've got a bunch of logs that I want to pass to S3. My current code looks a bit like the following (parsers and position etc removed for ease of reading):

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/log1
  tag s3.log1
</source>

<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/log2
  tag s3.log2
</source>

<match s3.*>
  @type s3
  aws_key_id (key)
  aws_sec_key (sec_key)
  s3_bucket (bucket)
  path logs/
  <buffer>
     buffer stuff
  </buffer>
</match>
```

What I'm looking to do is store log1 and log2 in different s3 paths. Something like:

```
<match s3.*>
  @type s3
  aws_stuff_here
  <match s3.log1>
    path log1/
  </match>
  <match s3.log2>
    path log2/
  </match>
</match>
```

The intention here is to not have to repeat AWS key data. I figure it'd work fine with a bunch of match statements, each containing the AWS key data, but I'd like to avoid that if at all possible (for ease of future administration). Is this something fluentd can provide?

Comment: If your tags always be in `s3.log1` & `s3.log2` then you can get second part tag as prefix to your S3 path. so path will be `path "logs/${tag_parts[1]}/" `. Try and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

In the Fluentd docs in the web site only this(sec_id and sec_key) method of configuration is given. But if you look at the [repo](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-s3) you may find several other methods. I think **shared_credentials** will help in your task.